# Device Preview and SDL Mobile

Tags: experience-manager, context-engine, contextual-image-delivery

I understand Experience Manager's Device Preview lets users choose a device to set:

- `userAgent`
- `orientation`
- `width`
- `height`

This can be seen in `devices.xml`.

```
<device name="Apple iPhone 5" icon="device.appleiphone5">
    <userAgent>Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A403 Safari/8536.25</userAgent>
    <orientation type="portrait">
        <image>
            <fileName>AppleiPhone5_portrait.png</fileName>
            <width>221</width>
            <height>531</height>
        </image>
        <viewport>
            <width>187</width>
            <height>296</height>
            <top>80</top>
            <left>18</left>
        </viewport>
    </orientation>
    <orientation type="landscape">
        <image>
            <fileName>AppleiPhone5_landscape.png</fileName>
            <width>465</width>
            <height>242</height>
        </image>
        <viewport>
            <width>332</width>
            <height>157</height>
            <top>27</top>
            <left>69</left>
        </viewport>
    </orientation>
</device>
```

The Context Engine Cartrdige includes properties for:

- Browser aspect, which includes:

  - `displayHeight`
  - `displayWidth`
- Device aspect, which has device properties for:

  - `displayHeight`
  - `displayWidth`
  - `mobile`, `tablet`
- OS aspect

  1. How does the Device Preview width and height relate to the Context Engine's aspects?
  2. How close the Device Preview get us to mimicing an actual device? By using Device Preview in XPM, should SmartTarget and contextual

Ian Homer has a [great explaination of how the Context Engine has a User Agent Parser](http://www.ianhomer.com/2014/05/sdl-mobile-context-repository-updates.html). What I'm not sure on is if the other Resolvers can "see through" the preview feature (e.g. "this really isn't an Apple iPhone 5").